# Odd behaviour when testing for equality in object literals

Tags: javascript

[Example of the behaviour.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Z0Z.png)

When testing for equality in object literals, `{} === {}` returns false (so does `[] === []`). However, if you write a function to perform the same test and pass an object literal as a parameter, the comparison returns true.

```
function foo(value) {
    return value === value
} 

foo({}) //Returns true!
```

Is anyone able to explain this behaviour?

Comment: `{}` are two different objects in `{} === {}` but `value` is the same single object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to this is because the expression `{} === {}` is taking two object *literals*, while in the function `foo` you are taking a *singular* `value` and comparing it against itself. In fact, `foo` will *always* return `true` (see edit).

A better way to look at this would be:

```js
const a = {}
const b = {}

console.log(a === b) // false, symmetric to {} === {}
console.log(a === a) // true, symmetric to (val) => val === val
```

edit: Ryan did point out that when passed NaN, it would short-circuit to `false` as defined in [11.9.3c](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

Comment: That last part is untrue, foo will return false if passed NaN.